finding a sequence that diverges
let $a_n$ be a sequence where for all $n\ge3$ $a_n \in (a_{n-1},a_{n-2})$ or $a_n \in (a_{n-2},a_{n-1})$
i need to find an example to such sequence that diverges.
i figured that such sequence is of the form of somthing like $a_n = \dfrac{a_{n-1} - a_{n-2}} n + somthing$
not sure how to go from here.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

$a_n:=(-1)^n\left(1+\frac1n\right)$

Since Anne Bauval gave the solution to the first question, I give a lead for the second question. If the sequence has at least 3 accumulation points, we choose exactly 3, say: $l_1 < l_2 < l_3$. Now by taking a small neighborhood around $l_2$, one can find a rank $n$ such that $a_n$ is in this neighborhood. But then this contradicts the fact that $l_1$ or $l_3$ is an accumulation point (why ?). Hint : look at how the sequence is defined based on its previous two values.

Please Id.d, don't pay attention to that stupid bot and restore your second question.

$a_n:=(-1)^n\left(1+\frac1n\right)$ is such a sequence.
Let us now prove that such a sequence only has two partial limits.
Assume wlog $a_1<a_2$. Then, $(a_{2n+1})$ is an increasing sequence converging to some $a$ and $(a_{2n})$ is a decreasing sequence converging to some $b>a$. For any subsequence $(a_{n_k})$ converging to some $c$, either $n_k$ is odd infinitely often and then $c=a$, or $n_k$ is even infinitely often and then $c=b$.
